# Calculate consecutive occurrences of a value above a threshold in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data for total sales per day for three people. I want to calculate occurrences above 70 sales per day. I then want to calculate the length of each event (event would be when consecutive days are above 70, e.g. an event would be 5 days in a row when sales are over 70 per day, or 2 days in a row when sales are over 70 per day). I would like a column that assigns the length of the event (e.g. 5 for 5 day, 2 for 2day) and when values are below 70 it should be 0. I want to be able to compare the length of events between the different people.

I can calculate occurrences (code below), but I am struggling with calculating the events with consecutive days.

```
set.seed(1234) 

#Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Create data
Date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-31"), by="days")
Tim_Sales <- sample(1 : 100, 3683, replace=TRUE) 
John_Sales <- sample(1 : 100, 3683, replace=TRUE) 
Rupert_Sales <- sample(1 : 100, 3683, replace=TRUE) 

# Make dataframe
df <- data.frame(Date, Tim_Sales, John_Sales, Rupert_Sales)

# Identify occurences above 70 sales
df_occurrences <- df %>%
 group_by(Date) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(sum(. >70))) %>%
 ungroup
df_occurrences
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses as an `ifelse` statement and `mutate` to create a new column, based on a set of conditions.

If a salesperson has more than 70 sales, subtract his or her number of sales from 70. Otherwise, the column equals zero. You can read more about the `ifelse` statement in the help file, accessed by typing `?ifelse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_occurrences <- df %>%
  mutate(Tim_70plus= ifelse(Tim_Sales > 70, Tim_Sales- 70, 0),
         John_70plus= ifelse(John_Sales > 70, John_Sales- 70, 0),
         Rupert_70plus= ifelse(Rupert_Sales > 70, Rupert_Sales- 70, 0))
```